# Como deixar bordas do ImageButton arredondadas?

Tags: android

Meu XML:

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle = "270"/>
        <corners
            android:radius = "25dp"/>
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele fica com a imagem retangular. Como faço para deixar a imagem arredondada como a borda?

Comment: Como vão ser os "estados" do botão: *pressed*, *focused* etc?. Coloque todo o código *xml* do botão.

Comment: estados do botao vao ser false